# Auto - Check Username

Tags: php, html

How would I go about auto checking the username a user enters on an HTML form? It is for a project I'm working on and need it finished. I do not currently have any code I'm working with now, haven't found anything useful on this.

Comment: What do you mean by "auto checking"? What server-side technology are you using?

Comment: Yeah... you can't "check" it using just HTML....you'll need to use a server-side language.

Comment: I use PHP on the server side.

Comment: What do you mean by "checking"?  Ensuring it's in a valid format?  Ensuring it isn't already taken?  Something else?  Also, are you asking how to do a "live" check via Ajax where users can immediately see the results of the check as they type a potential username?  Or just asking how to check it in the back end?

Comment: @Jeff! Yes! That is what I want to do! I want to do a "live" check to see if the potential username is already taken as they type the username. The DB is MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to construct your validation routine first before you can do anything.
I imagine it would take in a string and returns a boolean depending on if it finds the given string in the table of usernames.

Next, you have to attach a javascript event to fire off on keypress when the field is in focus. This Javascript event would pass the string in the field to the validation check. Then, you have to catch the reply and then react accordingly (display a success/error div or whatnot.)

I can try and churn out code if you want but the only PHP I know is using Codeigniter and the only Javascript I know is using JQuery so any code I will put out would be using those frameworks.

Comment: I have the PHP part done. I found a tutorial that used Ajax to do the rest. However, even if the username is invalid or taken, the form still submits. How coul I prevent it from submitting if the username is invalid?

Comment: You also have to do validation on the submit routine. You can't rely on client-side validation only because that's easily subverted. (I can just turn off javascript on my browser and I can wreak havoc on your app.)

Comment: Then how do I return the user back to the registration page (if the info is missing or taken ), without the user having to retype everything?

Comment: If you really want to prevent the submit to push through if the username is invalid, then here is a [sample code](http://pastie.org/1600835). Caveat: again, I'm using JQuery here.

Comment: You get the post data from the submit, put it in an array, check if all the data are valid. If they are invalid, pass the array back to the registration page. The registration page should insert the values back. Of course, the page should account for the case where the array/index is empty / not existing.